# XSLT Help to filter child element based on dates?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm working on a requirement to filter Child Elements for every Parent Element based on a date field. For each Report_Entry element, I need to return ALL FEIN_CHANGE nodes where a person has been active in any company in the year 2019. I have added sample XML and desired output to help understand the requirement. Any help or pseudo code is greatly appreciated.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR-TAX_REPORTING_UNIT">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:PERSON_NUMBER>2128984</wd:PERSON_NUMBER>
        <wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
            <wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>2002-06-03-07:00</wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>
            <wd:COMPANY>Columbia</wd:COMPANY>
        </wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
        <wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
            <wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>2011-10-28-07:00</wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>
            <wd:COMPANY>CBS Records</wd:COMPANY>
        </wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:PERSON_NUMBER>2169797</wd:PERSON_NUMBER>
        <wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
            <wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>2008-05-05-07:00</wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>
            <wd:COMPANY>RCA</wd:COMPANY>
        </wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:PERSON_NUMBER>2181815</wd:PERSON_NUMBER>
        <wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
            <wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>2014-10-10-07:00</wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>
            <wd:COMPANY>ACTIVISION</wd:COMPANY>
        </wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
        <wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
            <wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>2016-10-10-07:00</wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>
            <wd:COMPANY>BLIZZARD</wd:COMPANY>
        </wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
        <wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
            <wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>2019-04-01-07:00</wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE>
            <wd:COMPANY>Virgin ecords</wd:COMPANY>
        </wd:FEIN_CHANGE>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Expected Output:

```
2128984|2011-10-28|CBS Records
2169797|2008-05-05|RCA
2181815|2016-10-10|BLIZZARD
2181815|2019-04-01|Virgin Records
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this? Post your best attempt.

Comment: *"I need to return ALL FEIN_CHANGE nodes where a person has been active in any company in the year 2019."* I don't see that in your output.

Comment: Thanks Michael. If you look at person id #2181815, there are three rows in input xml effective dates corresponding to (i) 10/10/2014 (ii) 10/10/2016 (iii) 04/01/2019. Assume the end effective date is a one day minus next effective date, which would mean (i) 10/10/2014 to 10/09/2016 (ii) 10/10/2106 to 03/31/2019 (iii)04/01/2019 to NA(currently active). As you can notice (ii) and (iii) were active in 2019 so therefore appear in results. Ideally, the way I think is any FEIN_Node with eff date > 1/1/2019 PLUS Top of stack node < 1/1/2019. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, I'm stuck at very beginning not knowing which function to use to perform union of elements greater than 01/01/2019 plus latest row <2019. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your explanation correctly, every `FEIN_CHANGE` is effective until it is terminated by a subsequent one. And you want to show every `FEIN_CHANGE` that hasn't been terminated before January 1, 2019.

If so, you could do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/CR-TAX_REPORTING_UNIT">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">   
    <xsl:for-each select="Report_Entry/FEIN_CHANGE[not(following-sibling::FEIN_CHANGE[xs:date(EFFECTIVE_DATE) lt xs:date('2019-01-01')])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="../PERSON_NUMBER, xs:date(EFFECTIVE_DATE), COMPANY" separator="|"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdH9

Comment: Wonderful. Just worked perfectly. One last question - Let us say there is another element tag within FEIN_CHANGE called wd:Job_Indicator with values primary and secondary. How would I process them separately. I tried updating for-each statement but doesn't seem to be working as expected.```<xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry/wd:FEIN_CHANGE[wd:Job_Indicator='Primary'][not(following-sibling::wd:FEIN_CHANGE[xs:date(wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE) lt xs:date('2019-01-01')])]">```

Comment: ```<xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry/wd:FEIN_CHANGE[wd:Job_Indicator='Primary'][not(following-sibling::wd:FEIN_CHANGE[wd:Job_Indicator='Primary'][xs:date(wd:EFFECTIVE_DATE) lt xs:date('2019-01-01')])]">``` Similarly added another for-each statement for secondary jobs and I'm able to process them separately based on Job Indicator. However, the results are not sorted by ```PERSON_NUMBER``` as it executes primary jobs for all ```Report_Entry``` and then processes secondary jobs.

Comment: I think you need to post a new question.